# Unable to pass Facebook's session to UIWebview inside the the iphone

Tags: facebook

I am using the Facebook SDK for iOS (latest one) to authenticate and get user's access token. I am able to the graph api queries to get data and the authentication is working.

However, in one of my features, I am trying to open a UIWebView with a facebook URL (redirect url) and its asking me to login again.

Is it possible to pass the Facebook session that I am using in the native app to the webview so that the user doesn't need to login again?

Comment: did you succeed doing this? I have the same question.